# Regex Skip space in match

Tags: regex

I have a string of digits that represent 3 different lenghts. I need to pick out the second length in the string but can't find away to exclude the white space from the match. Here is an example for the string. It has always 6 digits after the dot but before it vary. In this case it is `907.086614` that I need to match exactly.

```
1417.322835 907.086614 2.267717

^\s(\d+\.\d{6})
```

I've played around with different look behind but can't get it to exclude the white space.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, my problem now when I have tried this in the application that will need this regex it doesn't have support for positive lookbehinds and positive lookahead. Bummer :-(

So is there any other way that can work without the positive lookbehind?

Comment: Use the second pattern in my answer. If it works tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

`(?<=\s)(\d+\.\d{6})(?=\s)`

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY6gR2/2)

But if you still want to use your pattern, remove the begin of line anchor `^` and match `group 1`

i.e
`\s(\d+\.\d{6})`

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY6gR2/1)

Comment: Thanks  James Jelo4kul the second pattern worked when used in the other application. I was doubtful that it would since the preceding space was selected as well but apparently it was ignored in the other application. Maybe because this value is considered as a length value by the other application.

Answer (score 1):

A potential side effect of `\s` is that it matches carriage returns.

[Example mistaken match](https://regex101.com/r/aY1kR9/5)

Since you are looking for the second column of a group of floats, it is better to be explicit:

```
\d[ \t](\d+\.\d+)[ \t]\d

^                          trailing digit from first col
   ^                       a single space or tab
         ^  ^ ^            capture float
                   ^       single space or tab
                       ^   leading digit of third col
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS8nW7/1)

You can also place the capture between a look ahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<=\d[ \t])(\d+\.\d+)(?=[ \t]\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS8nW7/2)

Answer (score 0):

How about with a positive look behind like:

```
(?<=\s)(\d+\.\d{6})
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS9iF7/1)**

**`(?<=\s)`** Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matches the `\s`

Comment: Yes I've tried that but it will also select the last part as well
I get two matches.
1. 907.086614
2.     2.267717

I only want the first part.

Comment: that is because your are using a global modifier when it seems it does not apply to your regex